# How can I prevent Desktop Users from viewing the wireless password?

Tags: ubuntu, wireless-networking, security, passwords

The title says it; I want to prevent users from viewing the wireless network password on Ubuntu. It's easily viewable through the included application called seahorse.

Comment: Um, this question has been asked forever ago, but just so other users know, there is option in seahorse to right-click on the "Login" folder and lock it. After that to view whatever network entries there are, you'd have to enter sudo password. Just sayin' . . .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume your users are unprivileged (no sudo etc.).
 
First delete the connection entry from the users' NetworkManager and delete the WiFi password from the users' keychain. Then log in with privileged account, open Network-Manager, edit the settings for the wireless connection and set it to "Available to all users".
This should allow every user to connect but viewing the password should need authorization with an account from from the "admin" group.

Answer (score 4):

This takes a good bit of mangling the way I would do it.  Take managing the wireless card out of userspace utilities(networkmanager/wicd whatever) so it isn't managed any more, remove the credential from gnome-keyring, set it to connect on boot and schedule a cron job to check every X mins if connection is up and bounce the interface if it isn't.  last, make sure users can't read the wpasupplicant.conf that holds your password

Comment: I've no idea if this works, but +1 just as it sounds good ;-)